# Difference between Data Model and Database Schema in DBMS?

Tags: database

I know the Data Model is basically two types ER-Model and Relational Model & Database schema is also two type Physical and logical.

But I can not understand what is the difference between them based on their operation in DBMS?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A schema is a blueprint of the database which specifies what fields will be present and what would be their types. For example an `employee` table will have an `employee_ID` column represented by a string of 10 digits and an `employee_Name` column with a string of 45 characters.

Data model is a high level design which decides what can be present in the schema. It provides a database user with a conceptual framework in which we specify the database requirements of the database user and the structure of the database to fulfill these requirements.

A data model can, for example, be a relational model where the data will be organised in tables whereas the schema for this model would be the set of attributes and their corresponding domains.

References: [Understanding the schema](http://globin.cse.psu.edu/globin/html/docs/schema.doc.html) and Database System Concepts (H Korth and A Silberschatz)

Comment: then what is the difference between data model and database model @richik iaiswal

Answer (score 9):

As I understand it, a database schema is a physical entity, it describes the structure of exactly how the data is stored and is itself stored by DBMS for reference. Data model, on the other hand, is an abstract representation of database.

Answer (score 3):

A schema can have multiple models related with it and each model can have multiple instances related with it.

for eg.

```
animalSchema{name:String, type:String}

mongoose.model('carnivores', animalSchema)
```

It simply means that carnivores is a model that is based on animalSchema.

```
mongoose.model('herbivores', animalSchema).
```

It simple means that herbivores is a model that is also based on animalSchema.

```
const lion = new carnivores();

const tiger = new carnivores();
```

These both are the instances of the carnivores model of the schema animalSchema

```
const deer = new herbivores();

const cow = new herbivores();
```

These both are the instances of the herbivores model of the schema animalSchema

Answer (score 1):

My Idea... A schema decides or describes the fields you will have in a document... while the model is the compilation of schema and ensures that any data moving in or out must conform to that schema

Answer (score 1):

The database schema is one that contains list of attributes and instructions to tell the database engine how data is organised whereas
Data model is a collection of conceptional tools for describing data, data-relationship and consistency constraints.

Answer (score 1):

From what little i have understood, Data Model is a high level design which defines the kind of tables, the fields in those tables and the relations between different tables. Database schema describes the type(int, string etc) and constraints like length of field should be less than 20 characters. Database Schema refers to the Data model and specifies each table and field in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Database schema**:- Database schema defines the database. This means it specifies what tables are there and how they relate to each other. It defines everything that will be useful for the DBMS software to use for understanding the database. This schema is stored in a separate file in the metadata repository

**Database data model**:- What kind of model will the DBMS system will use when handling data. This is not stored in a separate file. The data model is what the database is. ex:- Mysql DBMS uses a relational data model.

Answer (score 0):

In my view Database model is prepared first and Database schema is followed by that . Data model gives the overall logical view of database model specially in term of their entity relationship whereas Database model is more concentric on entity and their attribute.