# confused between term database model and database schema

Tags: database

I am new to database management system while going through my book , I got stucked on a term database model. Book says that database model is "logical design of the database" this defination looks very similar to database schema...so please suggest a proper defination of database model with an example . Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I in fact recently saw a very similar question and answer on this very site. I am sharing the link below. Hope it helps.

[Difference between Data Model and Database Schema in DBMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093452/difference-between-data-model-and-database-schema-in-dbms)

Comment: Thanks that worked....