# In what files are the Data Model and Schema declared in ASP.NET Core projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Going by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093452/difference-between-data-model-and-database-schema-in-dbms), I know that an ASP.NET Core project must have a data model and a database schema, if it has a database.

For months, I thought the data model resided in a Context class that inherited from DbContext. But I've come cross a tutorial that says this class is where the Schema lives.

Where does the Data Model and Schema get declared for ASP.NET Core projects?

Comment: What project are you referring to? Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

It uses EF Core (an O/RM). It uses [metadata mapping](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html) to define that database schema based on the [domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).